# What is the best way to construct NSError object by myself in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What is the best way to construct `NSError` object by myself in Swift? Is it ok to do it at all? I need to pass it to the some delegate function then.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dasdom The following code `var error = NSError()
error.description = "Error"` gives me an error "Cannot assign to description in error"

Comment: Sure, because `description` is not meant to be set. `description` is a property of `NSObject` which is mainly used for debugging. You should habe a look at the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/) of `NSError`.

Comment: @dasdom And what property should I use then? domain?

Comment: @FrozenHeart: Really, read the class reference. That's what it is there for.

Comment: Use the class method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSError/errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:

Comment: @dasdom In Swift, you'd use a constructor—they map to the Objective C class methods, e.g. in Swift `let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 5, userInfo: nil)` does the same thing as using the equivalent class method in Objective C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can user the constructor of NSError:

```
let ERROR_CODE = 101
let error = NSError(domain: "my.domain.error", code: ERROR_CODE, userInfo: nil)
```